# svn:ignore Tortoise

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I add a something to the svn:ignore entry, is that stored in the repository or in my local copy?

(In Tortoise, why items addet to svn:ignore appear on my changelist?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is stored in the repository along with all the other properties. This also explains why they're in the changelist: because you're changing it.

Comment: Can I ignore it locally? I don't want to add it to the repository, but  also I don't want to keep someone else from adding it.

Comment: Your can find TortoiseSVN's `config` file (I believe you can access it through it's preferences window) and add it to `global-ignores`. Besides that, you can't just do it locally.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using TortoiseSVN and always want to ignore it locally only, right click on the file from your commit dialog and "Move to Changelist -> ignore-on-commit". This is just a changelist that Tortoise maintains for exactly the purpose you describe. You could also just add the item to another changelist and choose to never commit it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [Global ignore pattern](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/ch05s25.html) setting.  This will only affect your working copies.  I use this to ignore Emacs temporary files, since not everyone uses Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring an item consists on setting the `svn:ignore` property on the parent folder with the name (or wildcard) of the item. Look at the "Properties" context menu entry of the folder and you'll find it there. As everything else, this changes are local until you `commit` them. In this case, you commit changes to the parent folder. You can also `revert` them if you haven't committed them yet.

It's important to note that this doesn't *remove* the item from neither the repository nor the working copy. If the item was already under version control, it'll remain there until you `delete` it.

The changelist feature, on the contrary, it's entirely local. However, you need to `add` the item to version control in order to move it to a changelist; changelists cannot handle unversioned items.

You can instruct TortoiseSVN to automatically ignore certain files patterns. Open the "Settings" dialogue, find the "General" section and edit the "Global ignore pattern" input box. However, this settings apply to *all* repositories. If you want to ignore specific files, it's probably better to `add` them and move them to the `ignore-on-commit` changelist.